# How to cite an online lecture in MLA?

Tags: biblatex, citing, mla-style, biblatex-mla

I'm using `biblatex-mla` to cite in MLA style, and I need to cite what a lecturer said in an online lecture. This lecture was conducted through Zoom, and there is no URL as such. I have read the [documentation](https://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-mla/doc/biblatex-mla.pdf), but there is no mention of how to cite such a source.

How should I cite an online lecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd have said, use `@misc` and add fields so that things look OK, but there is a small issue with `@misc` entries in `mla-new` at the moment (https://github.com/jmclawson/biblatex-mla/issues/23), so I suggest you take `@online`.

The following seems to give acceptable results

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=mla-new, backend=biber]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {Lecture on a Theory on Brontosauruses},
  date      = {1972-11-16},
  publisher = {University of Python},
  location  = {Monty},
  note      = {Online lecture},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{elk}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Elk, Anne. “Lecture on a Theory on Brontosauruses.” U of Python, Monty, 16 Nov. 1972, Online lecture.]

If the recording of the lecture is available via some route, you may want to include the relevant information in the `note` field as well.